# Makefile no encuentra .hpp

Tags: c++, ubuntu, c++11, makefile

Tengo 2 carpetas en mi proyecto, 1 llamada Builds que contiene el Makefile y un programa de pruebas (test-P0-consola.cpp) y otra llamada P0 con las clases fecha y cadena ( fecha.hpp / cpp y cadena.hpp / cpp).
La fichero test-P0-consola.cpp incluye a ambas clases, el problema es que al estar en diferentes carpetas el Makefile parece no encontrar el fecha.hpp / cadena.hpp, algo que no pasa al estar ambos en la misma carpeta.

```
CPP = g++
CPPFLAGS = -std=c++14 -g -Wall -pedantic

VPATH = ../P0:.:..

test-consola: test-P0-consola.o fecha.o cadena.o
    ${CPP} ${CPPFLAGS} -o $@.ex $^

test-P0-consola.o: test-P0-consola.cpp fecha.hpp cadena.hpp
    ${CPP} -c ${CPPFLAGS} $< -o $@

fecha.o: fecha.hpp
cadena.o: cadena.hpp
```

Tanto fecha.o como cadena.o compilan llamándolos de forma explícita.
PD: Usando Ubuntu y g++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de corregirte ese error en particular, tienes otros errores en tu makefile. Primero, `VPATH` lo declaras pero no lo usas.

Segundo, `CPP` no es el compilador de C++, es el ejecutable del preprocesador (`cpp`, el programa que `gcc` llama internamente para tratar los `#include`, los `#define`, etc, antes de comenzar la compilación). Tu compilador de C++ debe ir en `CXX`.

Te funciona porque has escrito explícitamente `$(CPP)` en el cuerpo de la regla, y se está sustituyendo el valor de la variable, que efectivamente contiene `g++`. Pero va en contra del propósito de la variable (y además, te puedes cargar las reglas implícitas de `GNU Make`).

Lo mismo con `CPPFLAGS`, que son las opciones del preprocesador. Las tuyas  deben ir en `CXXFLAGS`:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++14 -g -Wall -pedantic
VPATH = ../P0:.:..

test-consola: test-P0-consola.o fecha.o cadena.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@.ex $^ # ¿.ex?

test-P0-consola.o: test-P0-consola.cpp fecha.hpp cadena.hpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@

fecha.o: fecha.hpp
cadena.o: cadena.hpp
```

Ahora, el error por lo que preguntas. En el makefile tienes que poner la ruta relativa completa de los ficheros que pones como dependencia:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++14 -g -Wall -pedantic
# VPATH = ../P0:.:..

test-consola: test-P0-consola.o P0/fecha.o P0/cadena.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^

test-P0-consola.o: test-P0-consola.cpp P0/fecha.hpp P0/cadena.hpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@

P0/fecha.o: P0/fecha.hpp
P0/cadena.o: P0/cadena.hpp
```

Y aún así esto no solucionará tu problema. Al poner el fichero de `test-consola.cpp` fuera de la carpeta `P0`, y asumiendo que en las primeras líneas de `test-P0-consola.cpp` tendrás algo como:

```
#include "fecha.hpp"
#include "cadena.hpp"
```

Resultará que el compilador no podrá encontrar donde se encuentran los ficheros `fecha.hpp` y `cadena.hpp` desde `test-P0-consola.cpp`, y te dará un *fatal error* de fichero inexistente.

Suponiendo que la carpeta desde donde estás compilando es `/home/tu_usario/POO/practicas/`, y desde esa carpeta, compilas con:

```
g++ -opciones test-P0-consola.cpp -o test-P0-consola.o
```

Cualquier fichero que incluyas en dicho `.cpp` deberá incluir la ruta relativa con respecto a la carpeta donde se encuentre `test-P0-consola.cpp`. Si está en la misma carpeta, puedes poner directamente `#include "fecha.hpp"`. Si está en una carpeta diferente (`P0` en tu caso), tienes que modificar `test-P0-consola.cpp` con la ruta relativa correcta:

```
#include "P0/fecha.hpp"
#include "P0/cadena.hpp"
```

Pero en caso de que `test-P0-consola.cpp` no lo puedas modificar —código de los profesores, ¿a que sí? ;), lo más fácil es que le indiques a `g++`, que internamente invoca al preprocesador, `PATH`s alternativos donde puede encontrar más ficheros en caso de que, por rutas relativas, no los encuentre. Se hace con la opción `-I` (una vez por cada carpeta):

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++14 -g -Wall -pedantic
CPPFLAGS = $(CPPFLAGS) -IP0
# VPATH = ../P0:.:..

test-consola: test-P0-consola.o P0/fecha.o P0/cadena.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^

test-P0-consola.o: test-P0-consola.cpp P0/fecha.hpp P0/cadena.hpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@

P0/fecha.o: P0/fecha.hpp
P0/cadena.o: P0/cadena.hpp
```

Y `VPATH` te lo he comentado porque supongo que habrá sido uno de los intentos por añadir nuevas carpetas al path (lo que hay que hacer con `-I`). Desafortunadamente, `VPATH` no es ninguna de las variables implícitas de `GNU Make`, y aunque lo fuera, si creas tus propias reglas y no utilizas la variable, la variable no se usa. Las variables implícitas solo sirven para las reglas implícitas, o las reglas explícitas en las que manualmente las escribas (como `CXX`, que por defecto vale `g++`, y `CXXFLAGS`, que por defecto está vacío).

**NOTA:** Al cambiar la variable `CPP`, no estás cambiando la llamada que `gcc` hace internamente al preprocesador. Simplemente, es para uso interno del makefile (por si tú quieres crear reglas para preprocesar ficheros manualmente en vez de hacer que `gcc` lo preprocese por tí).